# React class method not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, jsx

I'm new to react and I'm trying to pull and display data from randomuserapi. I've made the api call but when I run my app, I get the error below:

```
./src/App.js
Line 45:  'getData' is not defined  no-undef
```

Here's my code below: The getData() method is where I make the api call. That method is now called in ComponentDidMount.

I also binded getData() to my constructor but I still get the error above.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      people: []
 }

 this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
}

getData() {
 const promise = fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20')
   .then(response => {
     if (response.status >= 400) {
     throw `Response Invalid ( ${response.status} )`;
     return;
   }
   return response.json();
 })
 .then(({results}) => {
   return results;
 })
 .catch(error => {
   console.log(error);
 });

 return promise;
}

ComponenDidMount() {
  getData()
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        people: data
      });
    });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{this.state.people.results[0].gender}</p>
    </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

I'm also using create-react-app from Github. Please some assistance will be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you reference defined methods you need to say `this` so:

```
componenDidMount() {
  this.getData()
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        people: data
      });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `this.` when calling your functions.
`this.getData()` inside `componentDidMount`